# Is this "Healthy (Primary Partition)" Needed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

I have a partition called "Healthy (Primary Partition)" that is 7.45 GB. Is it needed, or can I delete the volume?

Here are my partitions:

[image: Here are my partitions.]

Comment: That partition wasn't created by Windows.  The other partitions were created by Windows.

Comment: Its probably the Manufacturers factory restore partition, If you remove it then you cannot do a factory reset, unless you make the factory restore media before deleting that partition